# Netbeans doesn't recognize imported package

Tags: netbeans

I have 2 projects in netbeans, one of then import some classes of the other o should do it but when I try not get it to work. 
Project 1 is called gprslibs and project 2 is called gprs, the project 2 import some some classes and packages of the projec 1. The problem is that netbeans doesn't reconize de package of the project 1.
I think that should be an easy problem but I don't find the answer.
Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to import some packages and classes from Project1:gprslib into the project Project2:gprs

For this to work you will have to add the Project1:gprslib as a dependency in your Project2:gprs project

**Step 1**
Assuming you have two projects as mentioned above, gprslib and gprs.  In your gprs project right click on the Libraries node and choose the Add Project.. option

[image: Library Context Menu]

**Step 2**
Select the gprslib project which you want to add as a dependency to your project

[image: Adding project dependency]

**Step 3**
After this step the packages and classes from gprslib project will become available to the gprs project even in the hints and help from NetBeans IDE.

[image: NetBeans showing context help]